# cannot find symbol [ERROR] symbol: method getlogger(java.lang.Class<org.first.FirstMaven.App>)

Tags: java, maven

I am new to Maven and trying to compile a simple program using Log4j. When i compile the project using mvn compile then it brings downloads all the jar. I have already added the dependencies into pom.xml but not sure why it is not recognizing the slf4j.jar. Here is the program and snippet of pom.xml

```
package org.first.FirstMaven;
import org.slf4j.*;
public class App
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
          Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getlogger(App.class);
          logger.info("Hello World!");
    }
}

Pom.xml: 
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Error:

> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to
>   execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile
>   (default-compile) on project MavenTestApp: Compilation failure
>   /home/first/MAVEN/MavenTestApp/src/main/java/org/first/FirstMaven/App.java:[13,40]
>   cannot find symbol   symbol:   method
>   getlogger(java.lang.Class)   location: class
>   org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

Comment: It might be helpful to post the entire Pom.xml file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using **getlogger** (small L), its **getLogger**.

```
 public static void main( String[] args )
 {
      Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(App.class);
      logger.info("Hello World!");
 }
```

If you are using any IDE, try to use auto-complete feature (**for Eclipse Ctrl + Space**), to avoid such mistakes.

Comment: Gotcha!!!. I was using VI Editor on Ubuntu, and just trying with a simple program with Maven.. Thank you Hemant..